# How to compare two Geodatabases

Tags: arcgis-10.1, postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase, file-geodatabase

I would like to compare the data of two geodatabases, in SDE or a file geodatabase,  to detect the changes occured between them , i've tried to compare the Xml workspace document of both databases using notepad++ "compare plugin" , but it's not easy to check and interpret the differences.

i'm looking for a better solution.

Comment: have you tried feature compare ? http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000004000000

Comment: yes this function seems to be the solution :) , thanks

Comment: Doesn't feature compare looks for differences on feature classes? @geogeek, are you looking for schema difference between the whole geodatabase (all objects within it)?

Comment: i'm looking to compare two geodatabases having the same schema but with different data

Comment: are the changes in the attributes or in the geometry?

Comment: in both  , the attributes and in the geometry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by radouxju, the [Feature Compare](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000004000000) geoprocessing tool is your best option.  It can be found in the ArcTools under Data Management > Data Comparison.  Below is the tool's summary.

> Compares two feature classes or layers and returns the comparison results. Feature Compare can report differences with geometry, tabular values, spatial reference, and field definitions.

The tool is available ArcGIS Desktop since version 9.2 and for all licence levels (i.e. basic, standard, and advanced).